# The remote desktop keyboard is not working properly

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, remote-desktop

I have a problem with the keyboard on the remote desktop end of Windows 10 Pro (10.0.19045). When i try to type text, another character appears instead of the indicated character, when you try to press the same key again, the next/different character appears. There is some continuity. examples:

I press the "a" key several times

> 1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\asdfghjkl;'`zxcvbnm,./1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\asdfghjkl;'`zxcvbnm,./1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\asdfghjkl;

Holds the "a" key

> zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Numeric keyboard - I press the "1" key several times

> 01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456

Holds the "1" key

> 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999

Each time I pressed a different character appears with continuity as above.

Starting and typing on the touch keyboard is ok. In the local account, the keyboard works fine. I checked the region, language and keyboard settings. Everything looks correct. I recently did a Windows 10 update, but the problem appeared before. The problem does not occur constantly - it helps for a while, restart the computer, selecting "default input method" again - I have 1 to choose from or logging out of the user and logging in again. I scanned the system for viruses - found nothing. I can't find a dependency

Comment: Try using the on-screen keyboard on your local machine and type into the remote one to see if it's an issue with your keyboard. Try it on the remote machine too, to see if it's an issue with RDP? That said, it seems like some kind of weird accessibility feature because the `1` key stayed within the `0-9` characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling options in Windows helped

All Settings->Devices->Writing
Disable all available options in "spelling" and "typing"

More keyboard settings->advanced keyboard settings:

- override default input method - I chose a specific language, not a list.
- Language hotkeys->change key sequences:
  Language switching - unassigned
  Switch keyboard layout - unassigned